# Can we add Header information in Redirect URL in Azure AD while registering the App

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have configured an App in Azure AD as a multi-tenant application, I have added the Redirect URL. Can I Add header information with a redirect URL?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, do you want to add a request header to the redirect url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO!**

You cannot add header information to the **Redirect URL**. In fact, the Redirect URL is just a callback URL when you are completing the authentication. It is not a request URL. You cannot add any header information in it.

For more information about Redirect URL restrictions, please see:  [Redirect URI (reply URL) restrictions and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url).